Player holding ball in server but not on client
Yea so I was just making a sports game, and I basically needs a ball catching/holding system, It works on both sides on the first time but after I thrown it is just glitches out and the ball kept running away from me in client, but on the server side, It says that I am already holding the ball, I will add some notes to my code for better understanding.
-- This script is made in StarterCharacterScripts --

while true do -- a loop looping forever to check if the character is touching anything
    for i,v in ipairs(script.Parent:GetChildren()) do -- Looping through the whole body check all the body parts
        if v:IsA("Part") or v:IsA("MeshPart") then -- Checking if it is a body part (just to prevent it checking he humanoid so we won't get an error
            v.Touched:Connect(function(hit) -- see if the body part is touching anything
                if hit.Name == "Ball" then -- Checking if it is a ball
                    print("Ball")
                    hit.Parent = script.Parent -- putting the ball inside of the body
                    hit.Joint.Part0 = script.Parent.RightHand -- positioning it on the right place
                    print("Holding")
                end
            end)
            wait()
        end
    end
    wait()
end

This is the code I am using now, I still have one on the ball before.
local BALL = require(game.ServerScriptService.ModuleScript) -- requiring the base module

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit) -- Checking if the ball is touched by anything
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then -- see if it is a player
        BALL.Pickup(hit, script.Parent) -- Using the function from the module
    end
end)

Here is the module
local BALL = {} -- the table

BALL.Pickup = function(hit, ball) -- The function
    ball.Parent = hit.Parent -- setting its parent
    ball.Joint.Part0 = hit.Parent:WaitForChild("RightHand") -- positioning again
    print(ball.Joint.Part0) -- just for debugging
end


return BALL


I hope you guys can help me solve this problem
btw the ball aren't running away on roblox player but I just can't grab it

This is a really complicated question.  My very first guess though would be that the server, and the client aren't deterministic.  So you're checking for a HIT to determine if the ball is in contact with a player (humanoid) - but the calculation determining that is coming out different on the client, and on the server.  This term is called deterministic physics, and it's the boon of EVERY game developer making real-time online games.  (probably not, it's probably just me that hates this.)

Yo I actually think thats the case, cause the server side keep printing when I touch the ball but the client side never printed. But I wanna ask, even if we know the case how do I fix it.

Which physics library are you using to determine a hit between the ball and the player?

I don't really know what is that tho

How are you determining on the client that the ball goes from player 1 to player 2?  And on the server?
